# Regular expression to give no match on specific character

Tags: regex

I use `test_([^/]+)` but this only ignore the `/` character.

I want to give **no match** if `/` found anywhere after `test_`.

Example, what I need:

`test_apple` matches `apple`

`test_apple/` gives no match.

`test_ap/le` gives no match.

How should I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about: `test_([^/]+)$`

$ means look until the end of the string

Comment: +1 and [here is my Regexr link for this, that I do not need anymore](http://regexr.com?37m5k)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative lookahead to accomplish this:

`(?<=test_)(apple)(?![/])`

A Negative Lookahead basically means: "If you find this after this position, don't match."